# Java: How to merge the keys of two maps?

Tags: java

I am working in Java, and have declared two maps as follow:

```
private Map<MyCustomClass, Integer> map1, map2;
map1 = new HashMap<MyCustomClass, Integer>();
map2 = new HashMap<MyCustomClass, Integer>();

//adding some key value pair into map1
//adding some key value pair into map2

private ArrayList<MyCustomClass> list = new ArrayList<MyCustomClass>();
```

Now i want to insert the keys of both map in the above declared `ArrayList`. Is there any built-in method exist for this or i need to writes some custom code?

Comment: Merge? Do you just want to concatenate without checking for duplicates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add everything:

```
list.addAll(map1.keySet());
list.addAll(map2.keySet());
```

To add only unique keys:

```
Set<MyCustomClass> keys = new HashSet(map1.keySet());
keys.addAll(map2.keySet());

list.addAll(keys);
```

**References:** [`List.addAll(Collection c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29); 
[`HashMap.keySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
list.addAll(map1.keySet()); 
list.addAll(map2.keySet());
```

keySet() gets all the keys from the map and returns them as a set. The addAll then adds that set to your list.